# Adding coordinate system and projection information into TIFF file using GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, shapefile

I have a TIFF file whose output of `gdalinfo` is:

```
input.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: input.tif
Size is 30829, 40434
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2016:06:03 16:16:57
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  PREDICTOR=2
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,40434.0)
Upper Right (30829.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (30829.0,40434.0)
Center      (15414.5,20217.0)
Band 1 Block=30829x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=30829x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=30829x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

it loses the coordinate information and the projection metadata.

And based on this file, I have create a shapefile which contains some polygons.

Is there anyway to add the coordinate system and map information into this file and its related shapefile using GDAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one possible solution, it needs a reference TIFF file (noted as `ref.tif`) which contains the GeoTransform and the map projection information.

```
def add_metadata():
    maps = {
        'input.tif': 'ref.tif',
    }

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

    for k, v in maps.items():
        src_filename = os.path.join(src_dir, k + '.tif')
        dst_filename = os.path.join(dst_dir, k + '.tif')
        tmp_filename = os.path.join(dst_dir, '_nocompressed.tif')
        tmp2_filename = os.path.join(dst_dir, '_BeforeReproj.tif')
        ref_fileanme = os.path.join(src_dir, v + '.tif')

        if os.path.exists(src_filename) and os.path.exists(ref_fileanme):
            src_ds = gdal.Open(src_filename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
            ref_ds = gdal.Open(ref_fileanme, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

            src_trans = src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
            ref_trans = ref_ds.GetGeoTransform()
            src_proj = src_ds.GetProjection()
            ref_proj = ref_ds.GetProjection()

            if False:
                dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(tmp_filename, src_ds, strict=0)
                dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(ref_trans)
                dst_ds.SetProjection(ref_proj)
                dst_ds.FlushCache()

                dst_ds = None
                ref_ds = None
                src_ds = None

                if os.path.exists(tmp_filename):
                    print('reproject file')
                    time.sleep(3)
                    command = r'gdalwarp -t_srs ESRI::"E:\test_resampling\32650.prj" %s %s' % \
                              (tmp_filename, tmp2_filename)
                    os.system(command)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    if os.path.exists(tmp_filename):
                        os.remove(tmp_filename)
                        time.sleep(1)

                if os.path.exists(tmp2_filename):
                    print('compressing the result file')
                    time.sleep(3)
                    command = 'gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" %s %s' % \
                              (tmp2_filename, dst_filename)
                    os.system(command)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    if os.path.exists(tmp2_filename):
                        os.remove(tmp2_filename)
                        time.sleep(1)

            # change xml filename
            src_xml_filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(src_dir, k + '*.xml'))
            for src_xml_filename in src_xml_filenames:
                xml_postfix = src_xml_filename.split(os.sep)[-1].replace(k, '')
                ref_xml_filename = os.path.join(src_dir, v + xml_postfix)
                if (not os.path.exists(src_xml_filename)) or (not os.path.exists(ref_xml_filename)):
                    continue
                with open(src_xml_filename, 'r') as fp:
                    src_lines = fp.readlines()
                with open(ref_xml_filename, 'r') as fp:
                    ref_lines = fp.readlines()
                ref_coord_line = None
                for line in ref_lines:
                    if 'CoordSysStr' in line:
                        ref_coord_line = line
                        break
                if ref_coord_line is not None:
                    dst_lines = copy.deepcopy(src_lines)
                    for i, line in enumerate(dst_lines):
                        if 'CoordSysStr' in line:
                            dst_lines[i] = ref_coord_line
                        line1 = line.strip()
                        if line1[0] != '<':
                            coords = [float(val) for val in line1.split(' ')]
                            mapcoords = []
                            for j in range(len(coords)//2):
                                xmin = coords[2*j]
                                ymin = coords[2*j + 1]
                                x1 = ref_trans[0] + (xmin + 0.5) * ref_trans[1] + (ymin + 0.5) * \
                                     ref_trans[2]
                                y1 = ref_trans[3] + (xmin + 0.5) * ref_trans[4] + (ymin + 0.5) * \
                                     ref_trans[5]
                                mapcoords += [x1, y1]
                            dst_lines[i] = ' '.join(['%.6f' % val for val in mapcoords]) + '\n'
                    dst_xml_filename = os.path.join(dst_dir, k + xml_postfix)
                    with open(dst_xml_filename, 'w') as fp:
                        fp.writelines(dst_lines)

            print(k)

            # break

    driver = None
```

then, the `input_with_geo.tif` will have the metadata information, which is I think enough for post-processing. The `32650.prj` defines the Map information. The `*.xml` is generated from ENVI RoI tools.

In fact, if we do not have the `ref.tif`, we just need to define a map system (e.g., the system described in `32650.prj`) and the six parameters (i.e., the original point, the pixel size, north or not) in the `GeoTransform`, then we can also add the metadata in the TIFF file.